# uglify bundle file and have them both in webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, uglifyjs

```
entry: './app.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['env', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
              }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

this is my webpack config and it gives me the `bundle.js` file in `dist` directory. I want to uglify this `bundle.js` and want both `bundle.js` and `bundle.min,js` be present in the `dist` directory. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
entry: {
      'bundle': './app.js',
      'bundle.min': './dist/bundle.js',
    },

    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: "[name].js"
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      include: /\.min\.js$/,
      minimize: true
      })
    ]
```

Try this and let me know if it works!